# What is the difference between below two regular expression which represent 0 to 100?

Tags: regex, match, whitespace

1. `/^$| (^100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^\\d{1,2}([.]\\d{1,2})?)$/`

   The regular expression above passes `00.00` to `99.99` but not `100` or `100.00`
2. `/^$|(^100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^\\d{1,2}([.]\\d{1,2})?)$/`

   Above regular expression passes `00.00` to `99.99` with `100` or `100.00`

But only one difference between them is a space '' after `|` operator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `^` asserts position at start of a line. It can not assert potion because you have space in front of it. [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0WGo0a/1)

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space:

```
/^$| (^100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^\\d{1,2}([.]\\d{1,2})?)$/    
# __^ here
```

Remove it.

The second alternative `(^100([.]0{1,2})?)$` could not match anything because it is not possible to have a space before the beginning of line `^`

Comment: He knows about the space, see the line starting with "But only difference".

Answer (score 0):

The space makes a big difference. The first one will only match `100` or `100.00` if there's a space before it, since it's a required character in that alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `space` is going to invalid the second `alternative` :

`(^100([.]0{1,2})?)`

because it says it must start with a `space` character when it also specify a `^`.

The regex with the `space` is equivalent to the regex without the second alternative:

```
^$|(^\d{1,2}([.]\d{1,2})?)$
```

Let's see the following snippet.

```js
const reg1 = /^$| (^100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^\d{1,2}([.]\d{1,2})?)$/;
const reg2 = /^$|(^100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^\d{1,2}([.]\d{1,2})?)$/;

const str1 = '100';
const str2 = '90';

console.log(reg1.test(str1));
console.log(reg1.test(str2));

console.log('----------------------------');

console.log(reg2.test(str1));
console.log(reg2.test(str2));

const reg3 = /^$|(^\d{1,2}([.]\d{1,2})?)$/;

console.log('----------------------------');

console.log(reg3.test(str1));
console.log(reg3.test(str2));
```

For the help you can go to [https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

[image]